# Add class to container div based on content

Tags: jquery

I have some html mark up like so:

```
<div class="container">
<p class="date">October 10th 2012</p>
</div>
```

I want to add an additional class of October to my container div based on the month that is contained within the date wrapped in a

tag.

Is this possible with jQuery.

I intend to then take all containers with a class of October wrap in a div and then place that div into an accordion based on the months of they year.

Would really appreciate some help with this initial part.

Answer (score 3):

It sure is.

`$(".date:contains('October')").closest(".container").addClass("october");`

Note: it's case-sensitive.

Comment: Cant seem to get this to work here is my html [Paste Bin Link](http://pastebin.com/LrJNfntH)

`code`And my jQuery is as follows:
$(document).ready(function() {
      alert("document ready occurred!");

$("p.section-title:contains('October')").closest("div.event_data").addClass("october");
});

Answer (score 1):

```
var $divs = $("p.date:contains('October')").closest("div").addClass("October ");
$divs.wrap("<div></div>");
//Now place it into the accordion
```

Answer (score 1):

For multiple months:

```
var monthArr = ["January","Febuary","March","April","May","June","July","August","September","October","Novermber","December"];

for (var month in monthArr) {
    $("p.date:contains('" + month + "')").closest(".container").addClass(month);
}
```